# After npx create-react-app, modifying webpack.config.js inside /node_modules/react-scripts... does not work

Tags: node.js, create-react-app, ids, webpack.config.js

My goal is to change svgo module's config the way that it does not remove id tags from svg file while importing it.

I have App.js:

> import React from 'react';
> import logo from './logo.svg';
> import './App.css';
> import { ReactComponent as Complex} from './simple.svg';
>
> function App() {
> return (
>
>
>
> );
> }
>
> export default App;

This is the svg related block inside my webpack.config.js:

...........................

`{ test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/, include: paths.appSrc, loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'), options: { customize: require.resolve( 'babel-preset-react-app/webpack-overrides' ), presets: [ [ require.resolve('babel-preset-react-app'), { runtime: hasJsxRuntime ? 'automatic' : 'classic', }, ], ], // @remove-on-eject-begin babelrc: false, configFile: false, // Make sure we have a unique cache identifier, erring on the // side of caution. // We remove this when the user ejects because the default // is sane and uses Babel options. Instead of options, we use // the react-scripts and babel-preset-react-app versions. cacheIdentifier: getCacheIdentifier( isEnvProduction ? 'production' : isEnvDevelopment && 'development', [ 'babel-plugin-named-asset-import', 'babel-preset-react-app', 'react-dev-utils', 'react-scripts', ] ), // @remove-on-eject-end plugins: [ isEnvDevelopment && shouldUseReactRefresh && require.resolve('react-refresh/babel'), ].filter(Boolean), // This is a feature of`babel-loader`for webpack (not Babel itself). // It enables caching results in ./node_modules/.cache/babel-loader/ // directory for faster rebuilds. cacheDirectory: true, // See #6846 for context on why cacheCompression is disabled cacheCompression: false, compact: isEnvProduction, }, }, ...............................`

Comment: Stay out of `node_modules`, that's not where your work goes. Also, note that svgo is doing the right thing here: if you're importing SVG files, their id attributes don't matter if you're using them as img source, and their internal `id` values are incompatible with the document you're putting them in if you're inlining them directly as HTML5. Instead ask yourself why you need those `id` attributes, because React can already get to whatever you render out in the normal, React way.

Comment: Hey Mike! I am not using img tag to get id. I need id to change dymanically element parameters. Like doing domument.querySelector to change spesific element (by id) fill color value. So i need that id   when i target element with queryselector. If you know a better way,  react way, please share it...

Comment: No, you don't? The component you're putting the SVG in can always get to that SVG directly by [using a ref](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/manipulating-the-dom-with-refs). Even if you can't put the ref on the SVG element itself, you can put it on the wrapping element, so you can always get to its SVG child element for non-react DOM operations. But of course the followup there is "why do you need to perform DOM updates in a React application?"

Comment: After all, my goal is to present engineering schematics from svgs. For example, in svgs there might be some kind of meters and i need to change the color of the meter to smth dynamically (changing value from db). There are better ways to do this but plz telll me one you d prefer.

Comment: To sum up I am going to present client made svgs inside an app which grabs for ex fill color data from db. Ofc ill map db data correctly but this is my goal

Comment: Should I just js module for this functionality and import it to react or whats the best option here?

Comment: Just add a `ref` to that `<Complex>`, and now you can do whatever you need inside your `App` functional component, without needing an `id` attribute, or directly querying the DOM at all. You instead get the DOM element using your React reference. Also: please fix your post, because this is not how you use [markdown on Stackoverflow](/help/how-to-ask). And in case you haven't, give the ["how do I ask a good question"](/help/how-to-ask) guidelines a read over, because that will help you [edit] your post a bit, too.